# No visible @interface for 'UIWindow' declares the selector 'recursiveDescription'

Tags: ios, objective-c, recursion, uikit, foundation

**Goal:**

Get the view hierarchy into an instance of the `NSString`

**Code:**

```
+ (void)dumpViewHierarchy {
    UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    NSString *recursive = [keyWindow recursiveDescription];
}
```

**Error:**

> No visible @interface for 'UIWindow' declares the selector
>   'recursiveDescription'

[image]

Comment: Try it with `[(id) keyWindow recursiveDescription]`. It's a hidden property. If worst case you will have to declare it by yourself in an extension, without implementing it.

Comment: Is it safe for the App Store?

Comment: How to declare it in extension?

Comment: Since it's a hidden undocumented property, I wouldn't say it's safe for appstore. It might be unavailable outside debug mode.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27694502/669586 about an extension.

Comment: Small nitpick - Swift -> extension, Objective-C -> category.

Answer (score 0):

That is because uiwindow does not have any method named recursiveDescription. Probably you can use description property to print the description.